# ASP.NET MVC EditorTemplate not being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently making a website in ASP.NET MVC where i would like to use EditorTemplates to display a List inside my ViewModel. RowViewModel has a List of RowDataViewModels. I'm trying to make a Create View for RowViewModel, where i can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowData)
```

and therefore i need an EditorTemplate. I created and EditorTemplate under:

`Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RowDataViewModel.cshtml`

And i also tried putting the EditorTemplates folder under the /Home/ view folder, but nothing seems to work. No breakpoints are being hit inside the editortemplate. I think i did it this way before, but i might be forgetting something.

Any ideas?

RowViewModel:

```
public class RowViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<RowDataViewModel> RowData { get; set; }
}
```

RowDataViewModel:

```
public class RowDataViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate - RowDataViewModel.cshtml:

```
@using iDealWebRole.ViewModels
@model RowDataViewModel

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowData)` (not `@model.EditorFor(...)`)?

Comment: Just a typo in my post. Corrected it now :)

Comment: The code you have shown here is fine and will work correctly. There must be some other issue.

Comment: That's what i thought, right? I really can't find any issue with the code.. Can it be that i can't make and editor template for a viewmodel?

Comment: Yes of course you can. Are you sure you have named the `EditorTemplate` correctly (exactly as per the question)?

Comment: I copy pasted the names from my project :)

Comment: Are you sure the property `RowData` actually contains some items to render?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is here: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowData)`

You should use your editor for every row in RowData, like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RowData.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.RowData[i])
}
```

Comment: This would generate in duplicate `id` (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which will not bind to the collection on post back.

Comment: Edited answer to Stephen Muecke comment.